# Navigation animated underline from right to left

Tags: css

I need to make a navigation where on hover line appears from left to right and then on hover out it goes back to left.

I have got that far that I have it but it moves from left to right and then dissapears to the right, but I need it to go back to the left

```css
.underline {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  height: 4px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.underline:hover:after,
.underline:focus:after,
.underline:active:after {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="underline">underline</a>
```

So my desired result is that the underline goes back to the left on hover out.

Thanks!

Comment: what you want is easier than what you have: simply change the width on hover for 0 to 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my desired result is that the underline goes back to the left on hover out.

That only needs one single change in the stylesheet - position it from the left, instead of the right, to begin with.

```css
.underline {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* was: right: 0 */
  width: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  height: 4px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.underline:hover:after,
.underline:focus:after,
.underline:active:after {
  /* left: 0; */ /* redundant now */
  /* right: auto; */ /* redundant now */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="underline">underline</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `transform-origin:100% 0` for hover element,So the underline comes from right to left. If you apply `transform-origin:0 100%`  the undeline moves from left to right

```css
.expand{
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
.expand:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #000;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin:100% 50%
}
.expand:hover:after { 
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin:100% 0;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="expand">Underline</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the CSS god @TemaniAfif pointed out, simply get rid of all `right` definitions in both states, instead use `left: 0;` in the default state, and you're there:

```css
.underline {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.underline:after {
  background: #000;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: width .3s ease-out;
  width: 0;
}

.underline:hover:after,
.underline:focus:after,
.underline:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="underline">underline</a>
```